# Want to fix left nav list so it stays below navbar

Tags: html, navbar

I want to do something like this:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html

Where there is a navbar, a "jumbotron", and the nav list sits on the left. It sits below the jumbotron but when you scroll down it scrolls as well until it hits the navbar, then it scrolls down with it.

So far I have it so it scrolls down with the page but the margin at the top is navbar+jumbotron so there's a ton of white space once I scroll down. I can't seem to find the answer in the source code.

I've done this by fixing position of left nav list and floating the content on the right float:left with a left margin.

Thanks for your help.

```
<!-- start page wrap -->
<div id="wrap">

<!-- START NAV -->

<div class ="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navinner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav pull-right helfont">
          <li><!-- TOP NAV BAR LIST HERE -->
        </ul>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 



<!-- END NAV -->  


<div id="faq" class="container">

<div class="title">
    <h1> Frequently Asked Questions </h1>
</div>  

<div class="row">
     <div class="span3 offset1 faq-list">
      <ul class="nav nav-list" style="padding-left: 20px;">
      <li> <!-- NAV LIST HERE THAT I WANT ON LEFT -->
      </ul>
   </div>
 </div>

<div class="span7 offset3 faq-content">
  <!-- CONTENT ON RIGHT HERE -->
</div>
```

css:

```
 #faq {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

#faq .row {
margin-top: 40px;
 }

.faq-list {
position: fixed;
}

.faq-content {
 margin-left: 320px !important;
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've goten so far?

Comment: What's the website where I can paste my own html code and share the rendered website?

Comment: Most likely, JavaScript is used. I'd analyze the problem by considering how to do this in a way as close to normal behavior as possible: In this case, first fix the top navbar to the top, and also float the main content area, as you've already done. Next, add some javascript that sets the left nav element to `position:fixed` only after the page has been scrolled a certain amount

Comment: @user2559170 I use JSFiddle ([JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)) to paste my HTML, CSS, JS code.

Answer (score 0):

On the page you referenced, the behavior of the left-nav freezing in place once the jumbotron scrolls away seems to be achieved using javascript contained in the file "bootstrap-affix.js". If you are using the bootstrap framework, I believe you can get that behavior simply by applying the "affix" class to the element in question:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-list affix" style="padding-left: 20px;">
```

You should probably also remove the `margin-top` and `position: fixed` that you added, which should not be necessary for achieving the effect if you use bootstrap's built in `affix` behavior.